# Is the BCH version of Schnorr signatures compatible with taproot?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, schnorr-signatures, taproot

BCH is going to introduce [support for Schnorr signatures on May 15th](https://github.com/bitcoincashorg/bitcoincash.org/blob/master/spec/2019-05-15-upgrade.md). One of the most anticipated features for Schnorr signatures on Bitcoin is the introduction of taproot constructions. Will it be possible to use Taproot on BCH after the upcoming fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be possible to use Taproot on BCH after the hard fork. Taproot requires additional script constructions and interpretations of stack elements which the Schnorr signature algorithm by itself cannot provide. The BCH hard fork merely changes the signature algorithm for specific kinds of OP_CHECKSIG and OP_CHECKDATASIG outputs. No other changes related to scripts or the interpretation of stack elements is done.

Comment: To spell it out; hamfisted “first!!” implementations are a poor choice in a consensus system.